# Systemd service deactivates itself when USB device is pulled out

Tags: systemd

I have a task manager that communicates to an arduino over serial port, the arduino has an OLED display that shows the system's CPU, memory, swap, net download/upload, disk read/write usages.

The service is written in Ruby, and it never exits. If the arduino is pulled out and replugged, the service detects that.

To enable the Ruby script at boot, I have the following systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Arduino OLED as a Ultra Light-Weight System Monitor 

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/ruby /root/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/blink-tm
Restart=on-failure
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start it, it works just fine. But when I pull out the arduino, even though the code should work, the unit still deactivates itself! I also tried adding `Type=oneshot`, `Type=simple`, and `Type=forking`, but no luck

Here's the status of the service when the arduino is pulled out from the PC:

```
○ blink-tm.service - Arduino OLED as a Ultra Light-Weight System Monitor
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/blink-tm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-07-14 13:02:33 IST; 3min 30s ago
    Process: 3502 ExecStart=/bin/ruby /root/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/blink-tm (code=exited, statu>
   Main PID: 3502 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 115ms

Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.41: A potential device discovered: 1a86:7523
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.41: Changing baudrate to 57600...
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.41: Successfully Changed baudrate to 57600...
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.41: No device found. Retrying 2
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.91: A potential device discovered: 1a86:7523
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.91: Changing baudrate to 57600...
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:32.91: Successfully Changed baudrate to 57600...
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:33.41: Device discovered successfully. Path: /dev/ttyUSB0
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux ruby[3502]: :: 13:02:33.66: Device ready!
Jul 14 13:02:33 archlinux systemd[1]: blink-tm.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

As said, the Ruby script never fails, it prints some standard output. One example is running `/bin/ruby /root/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/blink-tm` from the terminal never exits when I pull out the arduino and re-plug it in.

So what could be the reason behind auto-deactivating service? I want to run the service as long as the ruby script runs.

Comment: `Restart=on-failure` checks the errorlevel of the executed program. Since you execute an interpreter, this interpreter will always return with errorlevel 0, otherwise your interpreter program might have a serious program error. I don't know if a ruby script can tell its interpreter program to exit with another errorlevel than 0.

Comment: Sure, ruby script can exit with other errorlevels, too... Anyway, added this because the previous version sometimes exited with some error, it's now fixed, and the ruby program never exits at all. But the systemd service still stops...

Comment: Maybe your script just terminates? (logical program error)

Comment: Tried my script in a terminal and it never terminates, but it prints logs of causing error without exiting. All errors are caught. If are interested you can check it here: https://github.com/Souravgoswami/blink-tm/blob/master/lib/blink_tm/blink_tm.rb

Comment: I would search for a possible logical error in `rescue Interrupt, SystemExit, SignalException` within your ruby script. Divide this `rescue` into 3 smaller `rescue` and use debugging tools/logger.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, let me check...

Comment: Yup, SignalException was the culprit, every time I unplug the Arduino, I get SIGHUP. No idea why it happens. This only happens from the systemd unit, but it never happens when I run this in terminal or even autostart on login from XFCE "application autostart" section.

Comment: Now I can surely trap SIGHUP, but I don't know why it's getting raised from the systemd service, any ideas?

Comment: Please log how often your service is being restarted and also check how fast it's being restarted (interval). systemd probably things your service is broken, because your service is restarting several 100times a second and thus systemd is terminating this service. You can adjust the time interval for restarting a failed service within the systemd unit file. I can't remember the exact value, but I suggest you read about how to create a unit file accordingly. As far as I remember the default value is only some milliseconds.

Comment: With the `Restart`, SIGHUP is logged only once and the service exits. If I use trap SIGHUP, the script continues to run even though the service deactivates. Removing the Restart didn't help

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue in a few line script that has Fcntl used. With Fcntl syswrite, I see that systemd sends SIGHUP when the terminal (arduino, /dev/ttyUSB0) isn't available. Again, this only happens with systemd unit, not in a terminal. Interestingly, the error (SignalException, SIGHUP) ruby raises is from `sleep` and not from `syswrite`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nHmqfGYG

Here's the script. Just merely opening the device with `IO.sysopen('/dev/ttyUSB0', Fcntl::O_RDWR)` and then sleeping will cause SIGHUP only from systemd unit. But if you run this in terminal, it won't get any SIGHUP. Also, commenting the `IO.syswrite(...)` line will not give you SIGHUP. I used `tail -f /tmp/x` to read the streaming logs... I believe it's a bug in either Ruby or systemd (most likely)

Comment: Wikipedia: _On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGHUP ("signal hang up") is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed._ **1st** Either systemd is killing your ruby interpreter, thus your ruby interpreter is telling its child process SIGHUP (your script) [I'm not sure with this.] or **2nd** the entire systemd unit service works as some kind of a terminal and systemd is killing this unit file service, aka terminal, and thus killing the ruby interpreter and also your script. I guess the **2nd** case is more plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the program from a terminal, the current tty is the controlling terminal, so opening a new tty will not change that.  When running from systemd, there is no controlling terminal, so `open(2)` on a serial port will make it the controlling terminal. Processes get SIGHUP when they lose their contrlling terminal. You need to add the flag `O_NOCTTY` to stop this. `man open` says about flags:

> O_NOCTTY. If pathname refers to a terminal device--see tty(4)--it will
> not become the process's controlling terminal even if the process does not
> have one.

Comment: Yes! By or-ing `Fcntl::O_RDWR | Fcntl::O_NOCTTY`, it doesn't get the SIGHUP any more...