# systemd mysteriously shutting down service at midnight

Tags: systemd, services

I run OwnTone service as a media server on my headless Ubuntu, and I noticed every other time I want to use the service, it is down and has to be relaunched.

Upon more inspection I have found out that systemd is gracefully stopping the service every day at 00:00:01, saying “owntone.service: Deactivated successfully”. No crash, no error, no kill, nothing.

This is strange, as I have no cron job or systemd timer directly meddling with this service and there is no timer or oncalendar clause in the service definition file either. OwnTone’s log concludes with an AirPlay timeout from hours before, so, unrelated to the shutdown.

I suppose a workaround is to relaunch the service everyday at 00:00:02, but if I want to solve the issue properly, how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Analyze the systemd file (`sudo systemctl cat {{servicename}}`) for the service itself and check if there is no *systemd timer* set up.

Comment: I have. There isn’t!

Comment: "deactivated succesfully" does not require that systemd stopped it - the process could have decided to exit on its own, or been killed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658311/systemd-service-deactivates-itself-when-usb-device-is-pulled-out . (For the list of kill signals which may be considered "successful termination", see SuccessExitStatus= in `man systemd.service`.)

Comment: How much of the computer's memory does this process consume?  I have seen long-running processes terminated by the kernel Out-Of-Memory/OOM killer when a cron job was started, such as Ubuntu's unattended-upgrades.  These instances were visible in the kernel logfiles or the main syslog logfiles in /var/log.

Comment: There is a maximum memory clause in the configuration file for owntone. I tweaked that to see what happens. For now it seems to be working past midnight…